# Codeigniter PHPMailer how to get the address and mailcontent using inputfields?

Tags: codeigniter, phpmailer

Good Day everyone who has an idea on how to get the message and add address using input fields.

```
public function send()
    {
        $this->load->library('phpmailer_lib');
        try
        {
            $mail=$this->phpmailer_lib->load();
            $mail->setFrom('rayjayabejuela@gmail.com','Rayjay');
            $mail->addAddress('flutterrun@gmail.com'); // I want the input data came from the input fields of email.
 
            $mail->Subject="Subject Matter"; 
            $mailContent=''; I want the input data came from the input fields came from the message.
            $mail->Body=$mailContent;
            
            if($mail->send()){
                echo "Email has been set";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
```

This is my view page page

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>email/send" method="post">
   <br>
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
   <br>
   <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message here" required></textarea>
   <br>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$_POST['email'];` or `$this->input->post('some_data')`?

Comment: This script you've written is of a type known as a **spam gateway**. It allows anyone to send arbitrary messages to anyone they like, claiming to be from you. That's a very bad thing, and will likely result in your server being blocked. If you want to make a contact form, look at the example provided with PHPMailer that does not suffer these problems.

Comment: yes sir ill check you repo github for the example contact form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function send()
    {
        $this->load->library('phpmailer_lib');
        try
        {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');
            
            $mail=$this->phpmailer_lib->load();
            $mail->setFrom('rayjayabejuela@gmail.com','Rayjay');
            $mail->addAddress($email); // I want the input data came from the input fields of email.
 
            $mail->Subject="Subject Matter"; 
            $mailContent=$message; I want the input data came from the input fields came from the message.
            $mail->Body=$mailContent;
            
            if($mail->send()){
                echo "Email has been set";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i'll try to help you. 
You can make a change from :

```
$mail->addAddress('flutterrun@gmail.com');
```

to this :

```
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
```

You can do this to mailcontent / messages too.